# Asterisk - Failed to authenticate device

Tags: exec, asterisk

I want to redirect flooder IP address with messages like "Failed to authenticate device" to my perl script.

I add in "chan_sip.c" after:

```
ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Failed to authenticate device %s [IP: %s]\n", sip_get_header(req, "From"), ast_sockaddr_stringify(addr));
```

this code:

```
execl("/bad-ip.pl", "bad-ip", sip_get_header(req, "From"), ast_sockaddr_stringify(addr), (char *)NULL);
```

But if flooder connects to the asterisk server, it falls with message:

> Disconnected from Asterisk server
>   Executing last minute cleanups

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way do that  is detect and log such flooding by iptable rules.

Use iptables limit target and LOG target.

It is not so nice idea put packet  level rate limiting into application level(asterisk).

Also there are already some suitable tools like fail2ban.org

Something like this can help(note, it is PART of firewall, need also do multiple additional check like checks for ssh attack and friendly-scanner invite)

```
# INVITE limit
$IPTABLES -A sipdos -m string --string "INVITE sip:" --algo bm --to $OFFSET -j sipdosinvite

$IPTABLES -A sipdosinvite \
-m hashlimit --hashlimit $IRATE --hashlimit-burst $BURST \
--hashlimit-mode srcip,dstport --hashlimit-name sip_i_limit -j ACCEPT

# REGISTER limit
$IPTABLES -A sipdos -m string --string "REGISTER sip:" --algo bm --to $OFFSET -j sipdosregister

$IPTABLES -A sipdosregister \
-m hashlimit --hashlimit $RRATE --hashlimit-burst $BURST \
--hashlimit-mode srcip,dstport --hashlimit-name sip_r_limit -j ACCEPT

# All other SIP packets...
$IPTABLES -A sipdos -m hashlimit --hashlimit $ORATE --hashlimit-burst $BURST \
  --hashlimit-mode srcip,dstport --hashlimit-name sip_o_limit -j ACCEPT




# Take action on everything else
if [ $LOG ]
then
$IPTABLES -A sipdosregister -j LOG --log-prefix SIP_TO_MANY
$IPTABLES -A sipdosinvite -j LOG --log-prefix SIP_TO_MANY
fi
```

Comment: I know fail2ban. But i need code for exec perl script. Can you help?